# Tensorflow stuck for seconds at the end of every epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, nvidia

I'm training a Neural Network over a TFRecordDataset. However, at the end of every epoch, i.e. with `ETA: 0s`, the training gets stuck for tens of seconds. For reference, one epoch takes around a minute to be completed over a dataset of around 25GB (before parsing a subset of the features).

I'm running TensorFlow 2.3.1 with a Nvidia Titan RTX GPU. Is this the intended behavior? Maybe due to the preprocessing in the input pipeline? Is that preprocessing performed by the CPU only or offloaded to the GPU? Thanks!

Comment: Its computing predictions and metrics on the validation data, nothing to worry about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a validation set and you're using `model.fit()`, it's probably the time it takes to calculate the loss and the metrics. In most cases, it should take an extra 25% to compute the metrics of a 80/20 split.